# Modify and open an existing Excel (xlsx) file with javaFx

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I'm pretty new to programming and javaFX and started my own little project for pratice.
Im trying to modify a simple existing Excel-Sheet. The User shall give some information in a textfield and the programm shall modify the excel sheet with that information and open it afterwards, when clicking a button. I'm using Apache POI to modify this Excel Sheet.

My Code looks like this atm (i'm sorry if the code isn't perfect - i just started):

```
@FXML
private Textfield name;

public class Controller {
    public Controller() {
}
@FXML
    private void showExcel(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {


        String eingabeName = name.getText();
        try {
            FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\hendr\\Documents\\Vorlage.xlsx"));
            HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
            HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
            Cell cell = null;
            cell = worksheet.getRow(1).getCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(eingabeName);

             File excelFile = new File("C:\\Users\\hendr\\Documents\\Vorlage.xlsx");
                if (excelFile.exists())
                {
                 if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())
                 {
                  try
                  {
                   Desktop.getDesktop().open(excelFile);
                  }
                  catch (IOException e1)
                  {

                   e1.printStackTrace();
                  }
                 }
                 else
                  {
                   System.out.println("Desktop is not supported!");
                  }
                }

                else
                {
                 System.out.println("File does not exist!");
                }       

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
```

At the moment it throws this Error:
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

and a lot of more red rows..

Help is much appreciated.

Full Error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1300(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(Unknown Source)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:126)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.storage.HeaderBlock.<init>(HeaderBlock.java:113)
    at org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NPOIFSFileSystem.<init>(NPOIFSFileSystem.java:301)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:413)
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.<init>(HSSFWorkbook.java:394)
    at application.Controller.showExcel(Controller.java:138)
    ... 58 more
```

Comment: Post the complete stack trace in the question. Did you read it and try to [diagnose it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450)?

Comment: The error code? I tired, but i failed. It's super long. But i gonna post it.

Comment: Seems pretty self explanatory: "The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)"

Comment: So it says my excel is a too new version?
How can i fix this problem?

Comment: But overall the code should work in your opinion?

Comment: Again, it says: *"You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)"*. I don't know POI, but wouldn't you just do `XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fsIP);`, etc etc?

Comment: Use [WorkbookFactory.create(File)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-) - handling both XLS and XLSX is what it's there for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promoting a comment to an answer...

The key line of your exception is:

```
org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.OfficeXmlFileException: The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents. You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)
```

Handily, that exception tells you exactly what you've done wrong:

> *The supplied data appears to be in the Office 2007+ XML. You are calling the part of POI that deals with OLE2 Office Documents*

And exactly what you need to do to fix your code:

> *You need to call a different part of POI to process this data (eg XSSF instead of HSSF)*

If you'll only ever work with `XLSX` files, change your current `HSSF` calls to `XSSF` ones

If you'll be working with both `XLS` and `XLSX` files, you should instead use [WorkbookFactory.create(File)](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html#create-java.io.File-) to have your file opened

Change these lines:

```
        FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\hendr\\Documents\\Vorlage.xlsx"));
        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
        HSSFSheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

To instead be:

```
File fs = new File("C:\\Users\\hendr\\Documents\\Vorlage.xlsx");
Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fs);
Sheet worksheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
```

And your code will now work correctly for both HSSF and XSSF